# Redis timeout issue

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am getting timeout issue with redis.

**Following is the exception**

System.TimeoutException: Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 1, mgr: ProcessReadQueue, err: never, queue: 7, qu: 0, qs: 7, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 507, ar: 1, clientName: EG-APP04, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/####, keyHashSlot: 12598, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1600,Min=800,Max=1600), WORKER: (Busy=187,Free=1413,Min=800,Max=1600), Local-CPU: unavailable

**Configuration: Connection string**
 connectionString="####,connectRetry=10, abortConnect=false, allowAdmin=true, ssl=false"

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your syncTimeout to a high value like below:

```
connectionString="####,connectRetry=10, abortConnect=false, 
allowAdmin=true, ssl=false, syncTimeout=30000
```

Comment: Tried still getting it intermittently.